# Is there a release date for Spring Framework .Net 2.0?

Tags: spring.net

I have posted this question on the Spring.Net forums, however I have seen very little activity there.  It seems that the 2.0 release has stopped at M2.  Does anyone know if the 2.0 GA version will be released?

Thanks!

Comment: Update:  I have reached out to VMWare / Spring Source to see what information I can get from the engineers there about the status of the Spring.Net Project.

Comment: I've been keeping track of this too. The latest commit was 10th April, although that of course doesn't mean there's no work being done behind the scenes. Hoping for a release soon.

Comment: Update: I got a response back from VMWare / Spring Source.  Looks like they are targeting Q4 year.  From VMWare:  "Got a feedback from engineering. The project is still active - engineering is targeting Q4 2013 for the release of Spring .Net 2.0."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a release date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing this question out, as I did receive a response back from VMWare via VMware Support Request 13313469304 :

"Got a feedback from engineering. The project is still active - engineering is targeting Q4 2013 for the release of Spring .Net 2.0."

Comment: wondering if that is still true, as long as only one month left in q4 :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is still true. I think when VMWare/EMC moved the SpringFramework projects to Pivotal - http://blogs.vmware.com/vmware/2012/12/the-pivotal-initiative.html - they decided to concentrate on Java only and dumped the SpringFrameWork.net project.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Framework .NET 2.0 has been released and is available on NuGet.

Comment: See TrustyCoder's answer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/releases/tag/spring-net-2.0.0-GA

Answer (score 1):

Spring framework.net 2.0 is finally released.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/releases/tag/spring-net-2.0.0-GA